# Generating XSLT in the following Scenerio

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I'm getting a following response from the back-end servers to display the data as quick links on the right side of the search results page.

```
 <NavigatorItems>
  <Navigator Name="Shoes">
   <Name>Nike</Name>
   <WebSite>www.nike.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Reebok</Name>
   <WebSite>www.reebok.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Adidas</Name>
   <WebSite>www.adidas.com</WebSite>
   <ShowAll>www.mysite.com/showallshoes</ShowAll>
  </Navigator>
  <Navigator Name="Clothes">
   <Name>Lee Jeans</Name>
   <WebSite>www.lee.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Levis</Name>
   <WebSite>www.levi.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Lawman</Name>
   <WebSite>www.lawman.com</WebSite>
   <ShowAll>www.mysite.com/showallclothes</ShowAll>
  </Navigator>
 </NavigatorItems>
```

I need to display these items using XSLT something like this:

[image]

The sample XSLT suggested by someone is something like this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="NavigatorItems/Navigator">
   <xsl:variable name="link" select="WebSite"/>
   <tr>
     <td><a href ="{$link}"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
   </tr>
   <xsl:test select="ShowAll"> 
     <xsl:variable name="linkShowAll" select="ShowAll"/>
      <tr> <td> <a href="{$linkShowAll}"> View More Results <td> </tr>
   </xsl:test>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

But it displays only

```
 Nike (with its appropriate link)

 Lee (with its appropriate link)
```

Where I'm going wrong with this ? I tried a lot to modify the XSLT and checked but no luck.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="Navigator">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></p>
  <ul>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
  </ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ShowAll"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="Name">
  <li>
   <a href="http://{following-sibling::WebSite[1]}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </a>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="ShowAll">
  <p>
    <a href="http://{.}">
     <xsl:text>View More Results</xsl:text>
    </a>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
 <NavigatorItems>
  <Navigator Name="Shoes">
   <Name>Nike</Name>
   <WebSite>www.nike.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Reebok</Name>
   <WebSite>www.reebok.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Adidas</Name>
   <WebSite>www.adidas.com</WebSite>
   <ShowAll>www.mysite.com/showallshoes</ShowAll>
  </Navigator>
  <Navigator Name="Clothes">
   <Name>Lee Jeans</Name>
   <WebSite>www.lee.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Levis</Name>
   <WebSite>www.levi.com</WebSite>
   <Name>Lawman</Name>
   <WebSite>www.lawman.com</WebSite>
   <ShowAll>www.mysite.com/showallclothes</ShowAll>
  </Navigator>
 </NavigatorItems>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>Shoes</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.nike.com">Nike</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.reebok.com">Reebok</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.adidas.com">Adidas</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<p>
   <a href="http://www.mysite.com/showallshoes">View More Results</a>
</p>
<p>Clothes</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.lee.com">Lee Jeans</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.levi.com">Levis</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.lawman.com">Lawman</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<p>
   <a href="http://www.mysite.com/showallclothes">View More Results</a>
</p>
```

**and the browser displays it like this**:

Shoes

- [Nike](http://www.nike.com)
- [Reebok](http://www.reebok.com)
- [Adidas](http://www.adidas.com)

[View More Results](http://www.mysite.com/showallshoes)

Clothes

- [Lee Jeans](http://www.lee.com)
- [Levis](http://www.levi.com)
- [Lawman](http://www.lawman.com)

[View More Results](http://www.mysite.com/showallclothes)

Comment: Awsome answer Dimitre..!!! Thanks a lot..!!!! Could you please provide me any online resources/sites to learn XSLT in more detail. I'm a beginner. Appreciate your help. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Sayed You are welcome. I have provided what I think are the best resources in this area in this answer to a SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: Dimitre: I have one more tag which is <IsScript> just below my each <WebSite> tag. This tag contains "true" or "false". I need to identify this while we assign the <a href>. so If it is true i will write as:

Comment: @Sayed: It is best if you ask a new question. Right now I am at work and will be able to look at your new question later.